# Command to check which all XMPP extension Protocols does ejabberd support?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

Is there a command or some other way to check which all XEPs (XMPP extension Protocols) are supported by ejabberd?

Comment: You can go through https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/protocols/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No direct command, but you can do the following magic from `remsh` (i.e. `ejabberdctl debug`):

```
> rp(lists:flatten(
     lists:map(
         fun(M) ->
            [Proto || {protocol, Proto} <- M:module_info(attributes)]
         end,
     element(2, application:get_key(ejabberd, modules))))).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XEP-0030: Service Discovery](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0030.html) for this. An IQ packet is used to query the features from XMPP Server and in reply of IQ packet, the server returns the supported protocols.